# Mocking Jersey Proxy Client Dropwizard

Tags: java, integration-testing, dropwizard, jersey-client

Basically, I want to Mock the proxy service client of dropwizard jersey.

```
WebResourceFactory.newResource(resourceInterface, webTarget)
```

Currently, Webresourcefactory takes an Interface which is annotated and return proxy client. And when we call any method on the return instance it creates the URL and hit it.

But I want that instead of doing that it returns the result as I declared in my concrete class which implements this interface.